# JSHINT tar unpack error

Tags: node.js, terminal, sublimetext3, jshint

I'm trying to install jshint to use with Sublime. I've successfully installed node.js and have installed SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-jshint packages but whenever I type `npm install -g jshint`

into terminal, I get the following:

[image]

have tried using `npm cache clean` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly says, you need to run the command as root/Administrator. Prepend your command with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g jshint
```

(assuming you have Administrator access), enter your password at the prompt, and the install will proceed.